# bash: for loop with unsigned integer

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over all unsigned int (32bits). I thought I could simply do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..4294967295}; do
  echo $i
done
```

However with bash 4.1, all it prints out is:

```
$ ./loop.sh
0
-1
```

I certainly cannot use $seq() construction, so how does one do a for loop in bash over all uint32 ?

Comment: One has to wonder what your use case is for iterating over that range *in Bash*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash 4.2`, I get a `SIGSEGV` with your example.  It seems that the problem is due to the fact you introduce `4294967295` + `1` number of arguments (essentially expanded by `{0..4294967295}`) in your `for` loop which causes it to choke.

Nevertheless, both the `SIGSEGV` that I observe and the incorrect behavior that you observe warrant that the issue be reported.

The [home page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) says that the main discussion list is `<bug-bash@gnu.org>`.

---

You could use a modified `for` loop:

```
for((i=0;i<=4294967295;i++)); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: In the meantime, while you wait for the bug to be fixed, could you simply break your loop in half?  `for i in {0..2147483647}; do echo $i; done; for i in {2147483648..4294967295}; do echo $i; done` so you don't run into the `SIGSEGV` that @devnull describes?

Comment: The C-style for loop is much better in this case. It completely avoids the problem. It's *sort of* analogous to using `xrange` instead of `range` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this many values would use up so much memory that it could never be done on any computer because it would take tremendous amounts of memory

Comment: it would take 2-3 Terabytes of memory

Comment: I counted 47GB to store all the text output. Anyway, the OP had to put *something* in the loop otherwise it would be a syntax error. It's normally assumed that the OP has meaningful complex logic that they are running inside their loop in their actual code.